# setVisibility() method doesn't work after calling AsyncTask in onResume method in activity/fragment

Tags: android, multithreading, httprequest

I have problem with handling response from server using AsyncTask:

-> I have activity. In onResume() method I call my AsyncTask to get some data from server:

```
 @Override
     public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //I convey instance of my activity to task, to serve response
        HttpTask httpTask = new HttpTask(this);
        httpTask.execute(url);
 }
```

My activity implements ServiceCallable to handle response:

```
 public interface ServiceCallable {
    public void onSuccessResponse(Object result);
 }
```

Code of HttpTask is following:

```
 public class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private String result = "";
    private ServiceCallable caller;

    public HttpTask(ServiceCallable caller) {
        this.caller = caller;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod(httpRequestType);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                result = readStream(conn.getInputStream());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        caller.onSuccessResponse(result);
    }
 }
```

Then in my activity I implemets onSuccessResponse() method to handle response:

```
 @Override
 public void onSuccessResponse(Object result) {
    //make something with result from service
    //....
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    //this doesn't work:
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
```

I don't have idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure that httpRequest works properly and onSuccessResponse method of my activity is called. I heard that something can be wrong because of calling setVisibility from other thread. Maybe I confused something with my caller (ServiceCallable) mechanism. I will appreciate if somebody could point me how should I change my code.

Comment: what exactly you want to do expect from the fact that `this doesn't work:`

Comment: Do you have the error log?

Comment: You might need to set the visibility on the UI thread.

Comment: "You might need to set the visibility on the UI thread." -> How to do that using AsyncTask ?

Comment: "Do you have the error log?" -> there is no error log: just my text view is still unvisible even I set visibility to 'View.VISIBLE'.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure `onSuccessResponse` is getting called then try setting the visibility on the UI thread:

```
@Override
public void onSuccessResponse(Object result) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    YourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `onSuccessResponse` is executing? Put in some `Log` messages to track what is happening.

Comment: I'm sure that onSuccessResponse is executing from debugging

Answer (score 0):

This my need added. I recommend you use other way with this library https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http instead of use AsyncTask

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("https://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        // called when request is retried
    }
});
```

You need check is INTERNET permission in manifest

And your `doInBackground()` need return a string

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod(httpRequestType);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                result = readStream(conn.getInputStream());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return result; // You miss this return
    }
```

Comment: I have internet permission turned on. Adding return statement doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: I think you need to use log.d to check which step of asynctask already work. and need check xml layout also.

Comment: I recommend you use other way to do get content from HTTP request with https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http. I will add on answer

Comment: I don't know how it could help with resolve my problem. As I said request is sended correctly and I receve proper answer from server. It works as expected. I only want to handle that response and make some element visible.